# Retrieving a list of choices for Digestive Functors from the database (Snap/Heist)

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework, digestive-functors

I have an address form that handles both adding and editing (Nothing if adding, Just Address if editing).  Up until now, I've had the state and country choices hard coded with a handful of items.

```
addressForm :: Monad m => Maybe Address -> [Address] -> Form Text m Address
addressForm a addrs = 
    Address
        <$> "id" .: choiceWith (addrToChoice addrs) (fmap id a)
        <*> "name" .: string (fmap name a)
        <*> "street" .: string (fmap street a)
        <*> "city" .: string (fmap city a)
        <*> "state" .: choiceWith stateChoices (fmap state a)
        <*> "country" .: choiceWith countryChoicesRequired (fmap country a)
        <*> "zipcode" .: string (fmap zipcode a)


stateChoices :: [(Text, (Maybe String, Text))] -- (htmlValue, (realValue, labelValue))
stateChoices = [("ON", (Just "ON", "Ontario")), ("NE", (Just "NE", "Nebraska"))]

countryChoicesRequired :: [(Text, (String, Text))]
countryChoicesRequired = [("CA", ("CA", "Canada")), ("US", ("US", "United States of America"))]
```

Now I would like to retrieve the list of states and countries from the database.  I could just pass the list of states/countries to the form like I'm already doing with a list of addresses, but this form is also a subform of 3 or 4 other forms (new advertiser form, new client form, etc.) and I don't need the list of states/countries outside of the form like I do with the list of addresses.

Here's the new form where I've just added fetching the country information:

```
addressForm' :: (HasPostgres p, Monad m) => Maybe Address -> [Address] -> p (Form Text m Address)
addressForm' a addrs = do
    countries <- countryChoices'
    return $ Address
        <$> "id" .: choiceWith (addrToChoice addrs) (fmap id a)
        <*> "name" .: string (fmap name a)
        <*> "street" .: string (fmap street a)
        <*> "city" .: string (fmap city a)
        <*> "state" .: choiceWith stateChoices (fmap state a)
        <*> "country" .: choiceWith countries (fmap country a)
        <*> "zipcode" .: string (fmap zipcode a)

data Region = Region
    { code :: String
    , fullName :: String
    }

countryChoices' :: HasPostgres m => m [(Text, (String, Text))]
countryChoices' = do
    countries <- getCountries
    return $ abbrToChoice countries

abbrToChoice :: [Region] -> [(Text, (String, Text))]
abbrToChoice regions =
    map (\ a -> ((pack $ code a), (code a, (pack $ fullName a)))) regions
```

Here's the handler that's calling it:

```
editAddressH :: ([(T.Text, Splice AppHandler)] -> AppHandler ()) -> Addr.Address -> Maybe Int64 -> AppHandler ()
editAddressH renderer a userId = do
    addresses <- Addr.list userId
    (view, result) <- runForm "form" $ Addr.addressForm' (Just a) addresses -- line 233
    case result of
        Just x -> do
            r <- Addr.edit x -- line 236
            case r of
                _ -> renderer [("success", showContents), ("dfForm", hideContents)]
        Nothing -> renderer $ ("success", hideContents) : ("addressList", addressScriptSplice addresses) : phoneSplices ++ digestiveSplices view
```

The error I get is this:

```
src/Site.hs:233:44:
    No instance for (HasPostgres
                       (digestive-functors-0.5.0.1:Text.Digestive.Form.Internal.FormTree
                          (Handler App App) v0 (Handler App App)))
      arising from a use of `Addr.addressForm''
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for
      (HasPostgres
         (digestive-functors-0.5.0.1:Text.Digestive.Form.Internal.FormTree
            (Handler App App) v0 (Handler App App)))
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `Addr.addressForm' (Just a) addresses'
    In a stmt of a 'do' expression:
        (view, result) <- runForm "form"
                        $ Addr.addressForm' (Just a) addresses
    In the expression:
      do { addresses <- Addr.list userId;
           (view, result) <- runForm "form"
                           $ Addr.addressForm' (Just a) addresses;
           case result of {
             Just x -> do { ... }
             Nothing
               -> renderer
                $   ("success", hideContents)
                  :   ("addressList", addressScriptSplice addresses)
                    :   phoneSplices ++ digestiveSplices view } }
src/Site.hs:236:40:
    Couldn't match expected type `Addr.Address'
                with actual type `digestive-functors-0.5.0.1:Text.Digestive.Form.Internal.FormTree
                                    m0 Text m0 Addr.Address'
    Expected type: Addr.Address
      Actual type: Form Text m0 Addr.Address
    In the first argument of `Addr.edit', namely `x'
    In a stmt of a 'do' expression: r <- Addr.edit x
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you need the [monadic](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/digestive-functors/0.5.0.2/doc/html/Text-Digestive-Form.html#v%3amonadic) function.  It might look something like this:

```
addressForm :: Monad m => Maybe Address -> [Address] -> Form Text m Address
addressForm a addrs = monadic $ do
    stateChoices <- getStatesFromDB
    countryChoices <- getCountriesFromDB
    return $
      Address
          <$> "id" .: choiceWith (addrToChoice addrs) (fmap id a)
          <*> "name" .: string (fmap name a)
          <*> "street" .: string (fmap street a)
          <*> "city" .: string (fmap city a)
          <*> "state" .: choiceWith stateChoices (fmap state a)
          <*> "country" .: choiceWith countryChoices (fmap country a)
          <*> "zipcode" .: string (fmap zipcode a)
```